# IdentityServer4 (v3.1.x) Entity Framework - Session not persistent

Tags: c#, session, identityserver4, persistent

I'm using IdentityServer4 (v3.1.x) with the Entity Framework package to allow the configuration and operational settings to be stored in a database. I've noticed however that for -some- reason the duration of which users are logged in to IS4 is determined by the IIS Application Pool 'recycle interval' setting, which I've currently set at 30 minutes. This is different from the expected behavior, of the users' session being as long as the access_token duration / refresh_token duration allows for.

When the IIS Application Pool 'recycle interval' is set to a higher value (1740 minutes max), the problem disappears. What I expect however is for the 'session' (for the lack of a better name) to be persistent between application pools and application pool recycles.

What am I doing wrong, and what do I need to change to make it work?

Durations:

- IdentityTokenLifetime: 300s / 5m
- IdentityAccessToken: 300s / 5m
- AuthorizationCodeLifetime: 300s / 5m

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    string connectionString = _config.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:IdentityServerDBConnectionString");
    var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
    
    services.AddDbContext<IdentityServerDBContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(
        options => {
            options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);  // As test
        }
    )
        .AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificate())
        .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        {
           options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
               sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        {
           options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
               sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
        })
        .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

    // Custom implementations
    services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
    services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
       .AddCookie(o =>
       {
           o.SlidingExpiration = false;
           o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);  // As test
       });

    services.AddAuthorization();
}
```

*EDIT:
As Tore points out in the comment below, the missing DataProtection implementation was the cause of the issue.

Using the links he shared I was able to solve it by adding the Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection package, and adding the following snippet to the Startup:

```
// Persistent data protection
services
    .AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToDbContext<DBContext>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookies are encrypted using the Data Protection APIs in ASP.NET Core and for production it is wise to configure this properly, so the encryption key/key-ring is persisted outside your web-application.

I did blog about the data protection API here:

- [Storing the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault](https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en)

See also these links:

- [Get started with the Data Protection APIs in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Data Protection configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: As an additional aside the IIS default app pool settings are stupid - at the very least change those so it recycles at a predictable time of day (or even not at all). Ensuring that your data protection and signing keys are in shared storage is key.  In addtion to the above this article covers the various aspects to consider: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/deployment.html

Comment: Indeed this fixed the problems I was having. Thanks!